# Enabling An AgentJob to run Depending on a previous agent and agentless job in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

Within an Azure Pipeline, I have an agent job called "job_3" which I want to run if it fulfills the following conditions:

1. If Job_1(agent job) is successful
   or
2. If Job_1(agent job) fails but Job_2(agentless job) succeeds. Job_2 runs only if Job_1 fails.

To start Job_3 in the pipeline I used custom variable expressions for it to trigger:
[image]

The expression I used:

```
and( eq(dependencies.Job_1.result,'Succeeded'), eq(dependencies.Job_2.result,'Succeeded') )
```

I get an error saying that there are cycle dependencies. What can i do to mitigate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An error saying that there are cycle dependencies.

The cause of this issue could be that there are cycle dependencies in the dependencies set by your jobs.

For example: Job_1 depend on Job_2 , Job2 depend on Job_1.

Based on your requirements, you can reset the following dependencies to fix this issue.

Job2 depend on Job 1  and Job 3 depend on Job 1 and Job 2.

In this case , the job_2 will run depend on the result of Job_1 and the Job_3 will depend on the result of job_1 and job_2.

YAML sample:

```
jobs:
 - job: job1
  
 - job: job2
   dependsOn: job1

 - job: job3
   dependsOn: 
    - job1
    - job2
```

Classic Sample:

**Job_1**

[image]

**Job_2**

[image]

**Job_3**

[image]

Comment: When I try this if the First job succeeds the second and the third are skipped. I want the third to run.

Comment: You need to modify the condition to use **OR** expression. `or( eq(dependencies.Job_1.result,'Succeeded'), eq(dependencies.Job_2.result,'Succeeded') )`. In this case, one of the two conditions is satisfied, the pipeline can continue to run

Comment: I tried or( eq(dependencies.Job_1.result,'Succeeded'), eq(dependencies.Job_2.result,'Succeeded') ) but the third job is skipped. I also tried or(  eq(dependencies.Job_2.result,'Succeeded'), eq(dependencies.Job_1.result,'Succeeded') ) still the third step is skipped

Comment: Can you check the log of the pipeline run and share the expression result ?